# error in pointer & multithread expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t’

Tags: c, multithreading

this code check sudoku ,with multithread.
when i running program after compile:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
int main(){
char t0,t1,t2;

pthread_t row,col,sub1;

t0=pthread_create(&row,NULL,row,NULL); //eror iz here!
t1=pthread_create(&col,NULL,col,NULL);
t2=pthread_create(&sub1,NULL,sub,NULL);

pthread_join(row, NULL);
pthread_join(col, NULL);
pthread_join(sub1, NULL);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
return 0;
}
```

and Error:

```
su.c: In function ‘main’:
su.c:87:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from su.c:4:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t’
su.c:88:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from su.c:4:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t’
```

my func is give 0 argument :void *sub();
and i'm sorry,my English is not good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void * my_row_function(void *param){ 
    Row * myrow = (Row*) param;
    //bla bla
}

int main(){
    Row * a_row= & row8outof9;
    pthread_create(&row,(const pthread_t*)NULL,
             my_row_function, a_row);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to pass as third argument a function (that returns void* and accept 1 argument of type void*), that function will receive a pointer that you basically have to cast back to the pointer type you passed in when calling `pthread_create`

Answer (score 4):

Prototype of `pthread_create` is this.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

In this, third argument must be a function that returning the void pointer, that takes an argument void pointer.

So make the function as above then pass that to the third argument of pthread_create.

```
void * thr_fn2(void *arg)// your function must be like this.
```

Then use that function as argument.